# Error: Invalid output format: IVS and PCAP format cannot be used together

Tags: arch-linux, aircrack-ng, pcap, airodump-ng

I'm using `aircrack-ng` to capture a handshake on a WPA2 access point. I would like to write the outfile in `pcap` format, but I keep getting errors. I've tried reinstalling `aircrack-ng` using versions from github and arch repository. I ultimately want to save the outfile in `hccapx` format for cracking with hashcat.

```
## OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
## Kernel: 5.18.12-zen1-1-zen 

## Name: aircrack-ng-git
## Version: 20220715.76370d0e-1

sudo airmon-ng start wlan1
# (mac80211 monitor mode already enabled for [phy1]wlan1 on [phy1]10)

sudo airodump-ng  -i wlan1 -c 6 --essid $ESSID --write "$ESSID-log" --output-format pcap
# Invalid output format: IVS and PCAP format cannot be used together.

sudo airodump-ng  -i wlan1 -c 6 --essid $ESSID --write "$ESSID-log"
# outfile: $ESSID-log.ivs

sudo airodump-ng  -i wlan1 -c 6 --essid $ESSID --write "$ESSID-log" --output-format kismet
# outfile: $ESSID-log.kismet.csv
# outfile: $ESSID-log.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have to leave out the `-i` string in the command, and just write the device name without it.

e.g.

```
## before
sudo airodump-ng -i wlan1 -c 6 --essid $ESSID --write "$ESSID-log"
# outfile: $ESSID-log.ivs

## after
sudo airodump-ng wlan1 -c 6 --essid $ESSID --write "$ESSID-log"
# outfile: $ESSID-log.cap
```